# How to extract the attribute in this class audio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the content of the tag `scr` in `audio`, which is inside the class `BlocArticle`. For example, one of such instances is

```
<audio id="229648fra2" src="/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229648fra2" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

I tried

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get('https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/aimer/1925', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

temp = [tag.attrs['src'] for tag in soup.select('div.BlocArticle audio')]
```

Sadly, my code returns `[]`. Could you please modify my code the achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css selector to achieve that,
`[class*='ZoneExpression']` means it will match both `"ZoneExpression"` and `"ZoneExpression1"`(`".*ZoneExpression.*"`):

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
r = session.get('https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/aimer/1925', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

r = [sub_tag.select_one("audio").get("src") for tag in soup.select(".itemZONESEM") for sub_tag in tag.select("[class*='ZoneExpression']")]
print(r)
```

Which gave me:

```
['/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229646fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/83614fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229647fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229648fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229649fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229650fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229651fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229652fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229653fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229654fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229655fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/2234fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229657fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229658fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229659fra2', '/dictionnaires-prononciation/francais/tts/229660fra2']
```

Comment: Your solution only selects inside `ZoneExpression1`. Could you please suggest an approach using `audio` for generality?

Comment: @Akira Do you want to get all the `audio` tags?

Comment: Yeap, but restrict to the subset `div.BlocArticle`.

Comment: I tried `soup.select('div.BlocArticle audio')` but failed.

Comment: @Akira Edit it, check the answer.